# What meaning is the phrase "be out in"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I came across this sentence:

> A tiny filed mouse **had been out in the wood** that day gathering nuts.

Does **had been out in the wood** mean **had been out from the wood**? If so, what is the difference between them?

In addition, does "A tiny filed mouse **had been out to the wood**" make sense?

Comment: There seems to be typos. "A tiny *field* mouse had been out *in the woods* that day gathering nuts." Source?

Comment: It is from a short story "Mr.Puff blow's hat" written by Alf Proysen.

Comment: @user3169: I agree about _field_, but _in the wood_ is fine in BrE.

Comment: @ColinFine Oh, I'm AmE, that might explain it. The only "wood" I know like this is Winnie the Pooh's "Hundred Acre Wood", but that is based on an English forest, so I guess I am *out of the woods*.

Comment: @user3169: Even in American English, *a wood* is not completely unheard-of; consider Frost's "Two roads diverged in a yellow wood". But yeah, it's definitely not usual.

Comment: "Had been out in the woods" and "had been out from the woods" do not mean the same thing.  I'm not even sure what the second one would mean because I can't think of a situation in which I would say that.  You can indeed say "had been out to the woods" but it has a slightly different meaning. It implies the mouse had made a trip to the woods. In that case you would have to end with "to gather nuts." "Had been out in the woods" means the mouse had spent the day away from his normal location and the place he spent that day was the woods.

Comment: @ bubbleking  I thought first "A tiny filed mouse had been out in the wood that day gathering nuts." meant " A tiny filed mouse had came out from the wood that day to get nuts.", so I wondered if It was used "in" but "from". However I notice my wrong now.

Comment: @ruakh: indeed. I seem to remember that in AmE one can say "a woods", which certainly sounds odd to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you say that somebody is **out** it can mean that they are not at home. The tiny field mouse was not at home, it was in the wood all day gathering nuts.

About people, a woman might say

> my husband is out at work all day